# Why did Mordecai forbid Esther to reveal her nationality?

Tags: esther

Esther 2:10 says:

> Esther had not revealed her nationality and family background, because Mordecai had forbidden her to do so.

Why not? Did the Persians hate Jews? Was there a racist issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verse bring up the question:

> Esther did not reveal her people or her kindred, for Mordecai had told her not to reveal it. (Esther 2:10, JPS).

While Haman had not yet been promoted to the following position, he probably was in a position to influence the selection of the queen.  Remember, the account of Israel defeating King Agag of Amalek is in 1 Samuel 15.

> Some time afterward, King Ahasuerus promoted Haman son of Hammedatha the Agagite; he advanced him and seated him higher than any of his fellow officials.  All the king’s courtiers in the palace gate knelt and bowed low to Haman, for such was the king’s order concerning him; but Mordecai would not kneel or bow low. (Esther 3:1-2, JPS)

Haman was most definitely after the Jews:

> But he disdained to lay hands on Mordecai alone; having been told who Mordecai’s people were, Haman plotted to do away with all the Jews, Mordecai’s people, throughout the kingdom of Ahasuerus.  (Esther 3:6, JPS)

While Mordecai did know ahead that this would happen with Haman, he evidently knew Haman would be a problem for the Jews and knew Esther's place of prominence could protect them.  But, Esther revealing that she was a Jew too soon might have hindered he move toward prominence.

> Mordecai had this message delivered to Esther: “Do not imagine that you, of all the Jews, will escape with your life by being in the king’s palace. 14On the contrary, if you keep silent in this crisis, relief and deliverance will come to the Jews from another quarter, while you and your father’s house will perish. And who knows, perhaps you have attained to royal position for just such a crisis.”  (Esther 4:13–14)

Haman was hit by surprise when found out Esther was a Jew.

> Queen Esther replied: “If Your Majesty will do me the favor, and if it pleases Your Majesty, let my life be granted me as my wish, and my people as my request. 4For we have been sold, my people and I, to be destroyed, massacred, and exterminated. Had we only been sold as bondmen and bondwomen, I would have kept silent; for the adversary is not worthy of the king’s trouble.”

> 5Thereupon King Ahasuerus demanded of Queen Esther, “Who is he and where is he who dared to do this?” 6“The adversary and enemy,” replied Esther, “is this evil Haman!” And Haman cringed in terror before the king and the queen. (Esther 7:3–6, JPS)

Thus, as far as we can tell by the book of Esther, Mordecai wanted to keep the fact that Esther was a Jew hidden from Haman and any other enemies of the Jews in the kings court.  The Jews had definitely made enemies of the people they had driven out of the land of Israel.

Comment: Yes. Historical! Haman was an Amalekite  - the people that God told Saul to completely exterminate, which he didn’t quite do. But even closer than just Jewish, Mordecai and Esther we’re both likely from the same tribe as Saul.